# Package not installing on virtual device

Tags: android, package

Am new to this and can`t get this bit of code to work on my virtual device. I get the following error message. Any input would be really useful.

```
Errors:
[2011-01-09 21:03:33 - Cat.Talker] Failed to install Cat.Talker.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-01-09 21:03:33 - Cat.Talker] (null)
[2011-01-09 21:03:33 - Cat.Talker] Launch canceled!
```

Cat.java:

```
package cat.talker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Cat extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

public void playSound(View view) {
 // First parameter defines the number of channels which should be played
 // in parallel, last one currently not used
 SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
 int soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.meow1, 1);

 // Getting the user sound settings
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
 float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
   .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
   .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
 soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="190px"
android:layout_height="136px"
android:layout_x="20px"
android:layout_y="12px"
>
</ImageView>
<Button
android:id="@+id/Meow1"
android:layout_width="197px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Meow1"
android:layout_x="16px"
android:layout_y="161px"
android:onClick="playsound"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/Meow2"
android:layout_width="196px"
android:layout_height="40px"
android:text="Meow2"
android:layout_x="17px"
android:layout_y="221px"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/Meow3"
android:layout_width="195px"
android:layout_height="42px"
android:text="Meow3"
android:layout_x="17px"
android:layout_y="276px"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/Meow4"
android:layout_width="191px"
android:layout_height="40px"
android:text="Meow4"
android:layout_x="18px"
android:layout_y="337px"
>
</Button>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: What's in the manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit too much "did you try turning it on and off again", but I do have this sometimes and then a restart of the virtual machine often helps. If it doesn't work you might even want to restart Eclipse (if you're using that)